# Grails Asset Pipeline - Set to Not Cache Assets

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I have a Grails application running in a customer's private data center. Users are complaining that the dashboard graphs are not updating with the system's status... The JS files are being cached on the client's local machines due to corporate settings on IE. Is there a way to specify a

```
    Cache-Control: max-age=60
```

with the Grails Asset Pipeline plugin? Or will I have to exclude the dashboard JS files that render the graphs and put this the cache-control setting in each file?

Comment: If you are using asset pipeline plugin,then there should be hash value at the end of file like application-837d5979e4ef3797bbaa42629ea278e3.js. So, there should not be problem of caching if you have changed in the file application.js because it will change the hash value.

Comment: It may not be the actual caching of the asset file. Because it actually should be pulling the asset from the cache, but it's caching the actual graph in IE. The asset file uses d3.js and pulls data from a REST endpoint. However, if you clear IE's cache the graph regenerates and is correct. So it kind of points to another issue, but since clearing the cache fixes it, I feel like it has something to do with the caching of the asset file.

Comment: @BrandonWagner then this might not be an issue with the asset pipeline cache. If you are making an AJAX call go get the data set the cache: false. Its your data that is coming from the REST service which is getting cached.